# Bulk Convert Entire Folder of Images with sharp

Tags: node.js, image-conversion, sharp

I have a project where I need to bulk convert large amounts of .png files to .jpgs, with some control over compression quality. Using the node module `sharp` works like a charm on individual files, e.g.:

```
const sharp = require("sharp");

sharp("input/82.png")
  .toFormat("jpeg")
  .jpeg({ quality: 70 })
  .toFile("output/82.jpg");
```

But I have hundreds of files I need to convert at a shot. I had hoped to be able to use some wildcard for files, like:

```
sharp("input/*.png")
  .toFormat("jpeg")
  .jpeg({ quality: 70 })
  .toFile("output/*.jpg");
```

though that of course doesn't work, nor has any attempt I've done to loop through all the files, or using the node module `glob`. Appreciate any guidance that can be provided here.

Comment: You mention that your attempts to iterate over the files have failed. What were those attempts? If you post the code, it will be possible to help debug it.

Comment: A fair request but, because I'm such a newbie and the attempt was so primitive, it never came close to working — nothing really to debug there, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of another developer, the answer turned out to be a bit more complex than I anticipated, and requires the use of the node module `glob`:

```
// example run : node sharp-convert.js ~/Projects/docs/public/images/output/new

const fs = require('fs');
const process = require('process');
const path = require('path');
const glob = require("glob")


const dir = process.argv[2];

const input_path = path.join(dir, '**', '*.png');
const output_path = path.join(dir, "min");

const sharp = require('sharp');

glob(input_path, function (err, files) {
  if (err != null) { throw err; }
  fs.mkdirSync(output_path, { recursive: true });
  files.forEach(function(inputFile) {
  sharp(inputFile)
    .jpeg({ mozjpeg: true, quality: 60, force: true })
    .toFile(path.join(output_path, path.basename(inputFile, path.extname(inputFile))+'.jpg'), (err, info) => {
      if(err === null){
          fs.unlink(inputFile, (err2) => {
              if (err2) throw err2;
              console.log('successfully compressed and deleted '+inputFile);
          });
      } else { throw err }
    });
  });
});
```

**NOTE:** This method is destructive and will delete any existing .pngs. Make sure to have a backup of your originals.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the npm package [images-folder-optimizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/images-folder-optimizer)